# Message received is "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

Tags: python, django, ajax, http-headers

I am using ajax to call the following URL:

"https://www.bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=usdt-btc"

I am getting the following error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have installed django-cors-headers and my settings.py looks like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'crispy_forms',
    # The following apps are required:
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
)


MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)


CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
)
```

Why am I still getting the error?

**I have read all the other answers related to this but they have not helped me. I have used the Chrome plugin too and it does work with it but I want a solution without it.**

Django Version = 1.8

Answer (score 0):

The configuration looks fine and according to the documentation. I just compared it to my configuration and it's almost the same. Since I use my API for only one website, I have it configured in my **CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST**, you can try this also to see if it responds.

Also, try removing all python cache files and restart the application server, maybe the setting where not loaded.

Comment: If you see I have also provided the address in CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST but still it does not work. Is there any specific way of removing all python cache which I am missing?

Comment: Try to remove the CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST option, it might cause some unintended behavior. With cache, I mean the .pyc files.

Comment: This is how my request headers look like:

* GET /api/v1/shops/ HTTP/1.1
* Host: api.domain.tld
* Connection: keep-alive
* Accept: application/json
* Origin: http://client.domain.tld
* Authorization: Token xxxx
* User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 *
 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36
* Referer: http://client.domain.tld
* Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
* Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,de;q=0.8,it;q=0.7,ro;q=0.6

Comment: The problem might be on your client. URL above is working when I try with https://www.test-cors.org

Answer (score 0):

It is not your app issue i.e. django issue as CORS is a http header which let's a user agent gain permission to a resource which is on a different domain as that of yours. It is a browser issue, hence adding CORS application in django will have no effect.
More information here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Try adding **crossDomain: true** in the ajax request